# Matrix Math in R on Large Datasets

Tags: r, math, matrix, bigdata

I've got a big square matrix, which I've taken the first row for testing purposes....
so the initial matrix is 1x63000, which is pretty big. Every time i try to multiply it by itself, using

```
a %*% b
```

Every time I do this, I get...

```
Error in fooB %*% fooB : non-conformable arguments
```

However, this works with smaller matrices. Are there any packages for handling mathematical functions of large matrices? or is there a trick I'm missing somewhere?

cheers

Comment: Do you mean by multiply it by itself: `a %*% t(a)`?

Comment: @agstudy It's been a long morning, thanks for catching that....

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the crossproduct, i.e. `a %*% t(a)` and there is a base R function for this. Try:

```
crossprod(a)
```